# How to sort a list that has strings and ints by size then output either int or string in python 3

Tags: python, sorting

I have this code, which will sort the inputs, but the only way it works is by the inputs being sorted before they are entered into the list. I want to re write the code to take any list and output the word or number, whichever happens to be second largest.

```
def secound_largest(values: {}):
    sorted_values = sorted(values.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True)
    second_maximum = list(sorted_values)[1][0]
    print(str(second_maximum)+ 'is the second largest item on the list')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_input_amount = int(input('How many items are in your list? '))
    dictonary_values = {}
    for amount in range(list_input_amount):
        list_input = input('Please enter your list item: ')
        if list_input.isnumeric():
            dictonary_values[int(list_input)] = int(list_input)
        else:
            dictonary_values[list_input] = len(list_input)

    secound_largest(dictonary_values)
```

Comment: Please focus your posting on the problem, rather than the whole of your current implementation.  For instance, it appears that your main program exists only to build the dict in question.  Replace this with a literal dict to illustrate your problem.  Include an example or two of current and desired output.

Comment: not sure how to edit the existing code like you did, but for instance[3, 5, 'python', 2, -1, 7] => 'Python'
[44, 33, 22, 30, 'Nashville', 3, 'bird', 11] => 33

Comment: Use the `edit` tab below the question.  Editing instructions are in the intro tour.

Comment: @devans If the list contains [1, 2, 3, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99] Is the "second largest" number `99` or is the "second largest" number `3`?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do what you want:

```
def argmax(subscriptable):
    _max = subscriptable[0]
    _max_inv = 0
    for idx in range(1, len(subscriptable)):
        elem = subscriptable[idx]
        if elem > _max:
            _max = elem
            _max_inv = idx
    return _max_inv

def second_large_arg(subscriptable):
    big1 = subscriptable[0]
    big2 = subscriptable[1]
    big1_inv = 0
    big2_inv = 1
    if big1 < subscriptable[1]:
        big1 = subscriptable[1]
        big2 = subscriptable[0]
        big1_inv = 1
        big2_inv = 0
    for idx in range(2, len(subscriptable)):
        elem = subscriptable[idx]
        if elem > big1:
            big2_inv = big1_inv
            big1 = elem
            big1_inv = idx
        elif elem > big2:
            big2 = elem
            big2_inv = idx
    return big2_inv

d = {
    0:23,
    1:83,
    2:999999999999999999999999999999,
    3:87,
    4:91,
    5:32111111,
    6:21
}
print(argmax(d)) # prints 2
print(second_large_arg(d)) # prints 5

L = {
    0:"apple",
    1:1,
    2:"SUBDERMATOGLYPHIC",
    3:"banana",
    4:99999999999999,
    5:2
}

L = [len(x) if hasattr(x, "__len__") else x for x in L.values()]

print(L)

print(argmax(L))  # prints 4
print(second_large_arg(L))  # prints 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
list2= []
list= [3, 5, 'python', 2, -1, 7]

for i in range(len(list)):
    try:
        item=[len(list[i]),list.index(list[i])]
        list2.append(item)
    except TypeError:
        item= [list[i],list.index(list[i])]
        list2.append(item)
list2.sort(key=lambda x:x[0],reverse=True)
print(list[list2[1][1]])
```

Comment: Thats how I ended up doing it